# How to bind angular bind @input with html element value

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and I want to bind the value of property bonded in for loop to an input value

for example : 
I want to bind name to next component input value :
`<input name="Name" readonly [(ngModel)]="item.name" class="form-control" id="txtName">`

`<other-component [userName] = "?????" ></other-component>`

Comment: Provide more details or share a demo link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<other-component [userName] = "itme.name" ></other-component>
```

if you're using in for loop

other-component.ts must have

```
@Input() userName:any;
```